# ASP.NET Web Pages - Change Websecurity.currentUserName value

Tags: asp.net, database, razor

I am building a simple web page in ASP.NET Web Pages 2 (Razor). I have used the StarterSite template, which, by default has a registration / login system. By default you can't have a username, just an email address and password. I altered the "UserProfile" table in the database to be able to add a username for those who'd like to.
When logged in, it greets me like: `"Hello, email-address"` where email-address is the address you are logged in with.

In code it looks like this: `"Hello, @Websecurity.currentUserName!"`

Basically, what I'd like to do is that the `CurrentUserName` property instead of getting the `CurrentUsername` as the email address from the DB, get the `UserName` Column's value.
This is my UserProfile table structure:

- Email - nVarchar(4000)
- ID - int
- UserName - nVarchar(4000)

How do I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it.
You need to change the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method in your AppStart file like this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Your DB Name", "Your Table Name", "What Column you want for the CurrentUserId as value", "What column you want for the CurrentUserName as value", true);
```

Hope this helps someone